What’s the recommended way to solve a cloud formation issue?
I have a large AWS CF template that I have worked on for about a year with hundreds of deploys.
Today I changed a the key on a DynamoDB table and the full stack went into Rollback_complete. The only solution was to delete the stack and manually delete a lot of resources as well, including an S3 bucket with loads of data. The account is only for dev environment so no real harm happened, but I really don’t want it to happen again.
Should the CF stack have other parameters for “on fail” or are there other solutions for this?
I still can’t understand why a small change like this could ruin the whole stack…

I think you may be misreading this. Your DynamoDB key change was unsuccessful (because changing keys is not a valid operation afaik) so the deployment failed and was rolled back. You didn't subsequently have to go and delete everything. You should have made a valid change e.g. delete the DynamoDB table from the CF template, re-deploy, then introduce the modified table to the template, then re-deploy. Obviously, if the data in the table was important then you would also need to arrange to export it first and later import it.

I see - that makes sense. But when I was that stupid and deleted everything - is there a backup somewhere?

Typically for DynamoDB you would enable Point In Time Recovery (PITR). I'm not sure if it's enabled by default. S3 buckets are not backed up by default (they can be very large with millions of objects). Also note that going forward you may want to enable DeletionPolicy so that important resources with data are retained when a CloudFormation stack is deleted.

AWS documentation provides an article to handle these situations where CloudFormation cannot be updated via re-deployment and as mentioned in other answers deletion of complete stack should be only used when nothing works (Not applicable for production). You can refer article: Handling CloudFormation Rollback

You changed a key in DynamoDB, means resource has to be deleted and created again, if table has data CF failed to delete it. Means whole rollback and nothign changed.
FYI: It is only limitation with KEY, You can do it with non-key attribute.
Changing key of dynamo db table "with data" and "without recreation" is not supported using CF or any other like Terraform. It is limitation with dynamo DB not CloudaFormation or Terraform.

Ok, but issues like these could happen when e.g the developer doesn't know about these restrictions. Aren't there a way to safeguard the rest of the CF stack against it, so that only the DDB error is raised and the rest of the stack are kept as is?

The rest of the stack was kept as is. In fact, nothing changed. Your deployment failed and was rolled back. At that point, both the DynamoDB table and S3 bucket(s) were intact and unchanged. Unfortunately, you then decided to delete the stack which is what actually caused the resources to be deleted. Fortunately, it sounds like this was not a critical or production workload.

Yeah, that sounds correct. But I tried to change the CF template and deploy and then it said the stack was in rollback complete and couldn’t be deployed. I thought deleting it was the only thing to do…
